# How do I find the leafs of a decision regression tree?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, spark-graphx

Idea: Instead of outputting an aggregate of data in the leaf, fit a linear regression model to that data

One model per leaf

When predicting, first find the leaf using DRT, then use the corresponding LM to do the final prediction

So far I have implemented the DRT. Then I tuned the parameters with crossvalidation. My question is, how do I apply the linear regression model on a particular bin generated by a crossvalidator?

Comment: Not sure about what your question is. Perhaps you could include some code?

Comment: @Luc Thanks for your reply. I've included a link to my code here: https://pastebin.com/D7c4VBV5 . What I'm trying to do is get a listing of the bins from crossval_model to then apply linear regression on. The objective is train, validate, and test the linear regression tree using the existing code.

Comment: I don't think that works with out of the box spark ml models. What you would need to do is building this class from scratch. Probably you can inherit from DRT class and only need to change the line where usually the aggregation in a leaf happens. However note that this would need to be done in scala